# nested gcp logging query: pipe an output of first query to a second query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I need to collect queries from gcp under the following scenario. First, I need to collect logs from *container c1* having a *textpayload: key1*. As per the logging util, the output of the this log will contain a *timestamp t*. In this context, I need now to  retrieve the logs from a *container c2* having the *timestamp t*.

Any hint  on how (the most efficient/brief) to write this query using gcp logging query language?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query to retrieve logs from container 2 with timestamp t, obtained from a previous query on container c1:

```
fetch container(c2)
where timestamp = (
  fetch container(c1)
  where textPayload: "key1"
  | timestamp
)
```